# Apply multiple condition groupby + sort + sum to pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that has the following columns:

Acct Num, Correspondence Date, Open Date

For each opened account, I am being asked to look back at all the correspondences that happened within
30 days of opendate of that account, then assigning points as following to the correspondences:

```
Forty-twenty-forty: Attribute 40% (0.4 points) of the attribution to the first touch,
40% to the last touch, and divide the remaining 20% between all touches in between
```

So I know apply and group by functions, but this is beyond my paygrade.
I have to group by account, with conditional based on comparison of 2 columns against eachother,
I have to do that to get a total number of correspondences, and I guess they have to be sorted as well, as the following step of assigning points to correspondences depends on the order in which they occurred.

I would like to do this efficiently, as I have a ton of rows, I know apply() can go fast, but I am pretty bad at *applying* it when the row-level operation I am trying to do gets even a little complex.

I appreciate any help, as I am not good at pandas.

**EDIT**
as per request

```
Acct, ContactDate, OpenDate, Points (what I need to calculate)
123, 1/1/2018, 1/1/2021, 0 (because correspondance not within 30 days of open)
123, 12/10/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.4 (first touch gets 0.4)
123, 12/11/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.2 (other 'touches' get 0.2/(num of touches-2) 'points')
123, 12/12/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.4 (last touch gets 0.4)
456, 1/1/2018, 1/1/2021, 0 (again, because correspondance not within 30 days of open)
456, 12/10/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.4 (first touch gets 0.4)
456, 12/11/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.1 (other 'touches' get 0.2/(num of touches-2) 'points')
456, 12/11/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.1 (other 'touches' get 0.2/(num of touches-2) 'points')
456, 12/12/2020, 1/1/2021, 0.4 (last touch gets 0.4)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by assigning points. Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Yes. I will post an edit

Comment: What happens if the first or last touch is the same as other touches? e.g. what if an acct has 3 correspondence and all of them occur in the same day? If this is not an issue then Jonathan's answer below seems to do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a reduced dataframe in that it excludes timeframes exceeding 30 days and then merges the original df into it get all the data in one df. This assumes your date sorting is correct, otherwise, you may have to do that upfront before applying the function below.

```
df['Points'] = 0 #add column to dataframe before analysis

#df.columns
#Index(['Acct', 'ContactDate', 'OpenDate', 'Points'], dtype='object')

def points(x):
    newx = x.loc[(x['OpenDate'] - x['ContactDate']) <= timedelta(days=30)] # reduce for wide > 30 days
    # print(newx.Acct)
    if newx.Acct.count() > 2: # check more than two dates exist
        newx['Points'].iloc[0] = .4 # first row
        newx['Points'].iloc[-1] = .4 # last row
        newx['Points'].iloc[1:-1] = .2 / newx['Points'].iloc[1:-1].count() # middle rows / by count of those rows
        return newx
    elif newx.Acct.count() == 2: # placeholder for later
        #edge case logic here for two occurences
        return newx
    elif newx.Acct.count() == 1: # placeholder for later
        #edge case logic here one onccurence
        return newx

# groupby Acct then clean up the indices so it can be merged back into original df
dft = df.groupby('Acct', as_index=False).apply(points).reset_index().set_index('level_1').drop('level_0', axis=1)

# merge on index
df_points = df[['Acct', 'ContactDate', 'OpenDate']].merge(dft['Points'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   Acct ContactDate   OpenDate  Points
0   123  2018-01-01 2021-01-01     0.0
1   123  2020-12-10 2021-01-01     0.4
2   123  2020-12-11 2021-01-01     0.2
3   123  2020-12-12 2021-01-01     0.4
4   456  2018-01-01 2021-01-01     0.0
5   456  2020-12-10 2021-01-01     0.4
6   456  2020-12-11 2021-01-01     0.1
7   456  2020-12-11 2021-01-01     0.1
8   456  2020-12-12 2021-01-01     0.4
```

Comment: Thank you! NEVER would have figured out the reset_index/set_index stuff